# Interpreting IV for continuous treatment and continuous instrument

Tags: references, assumptions, instrumental-variables, treatment-effect

Most standard IV framework looks at cases when both treatment (let's denote by $D$) and instrument (let's denote by $Z$) is binary. Let $Y(D)$ be the potential outcome (by using this notation, I'm implicitly assuming exclusion restriction). In this case, we have the following assumptions:

1. Exogeneity: $Y(1), Y(0), D(1), D(0)$ is independent of $Z$
2. Relevance: $P\{D(1) > D(0)\} > 0$
3. Monotonicity: $P\{D(1) \geq D(0)\} = 1$
4. $0 < P\{Z=1\} < 1$.

We say that under these assumptions, IV estimand recovers local average treatment effect (LATE) for the compliers.

However, two things are not clear to me:

1. How does this assumptions extend to cases with continuous treatment and continuous instrument?
2. How do you interpret the IV estimand with continuous treatment and continuous instrument? Specifically, who are the compliers?

Any reference or papers that talks about this issue will be welcomed! It seems to be quite basic question but quick Google search did not result in any clear answer for me.

Comment: Are you familiar with linear regression?

Comment: I ask because while the answer isn't just "use linear regression", linear models will be its building block.

Comment: In your answer, you can assume that the audience have a relatively good understanding of linear regression, enough to follow through academic papers that covers this topic.